# from a normal list, make list of parent,child pairs and subsequently a nested dictionary

Tags: json, algorithm, tree, nested, parent-child

I'd like to create a json/ nested dictionary a list that is structured as follows:

```
print(header_styles)
[('Heading 0', 'Essay',1), 
('Heading 1', 'Introduction',2), 
('Heading 2', 'the outline',3),
('Heading 3', 'The basics',4), 
('Heading 1', 'Results',5), 
('Heading 1', 'Methods',6), 
('Heading 2', 'Calculations',7), 
('Heading 3', 'algorithms',8), 
('Heading 4', 'Algorithm 1',9),
('Heading 4', 'Algorithm 2',10), 
('Heading 1', 'Conclusion',11)]
```

I would like to convert this list to a nested dictionary (to put in a json file) as below:

```
{
 name:'Essay',
 children:[{
              name:'Introduction'
              children:[{
                           name:'the outline',
                           children:[{
                                        name:'The basics'
                                        children:[]
                                    }]
                       }]
           },
           {
              name:'Results'
              children:[]
           },
           {
              name:'Methods',
              children:[{
                    name:'Calculations',
                    children:[{
                             name:'algorithm 1',
                             children:[]
                             },{
                             name:'algorithm 2'
                             children:[]
                             }]
              }]
           },
           {
           name:'Conclusion'
           children:[]
           }
     ]         
}
```

So as you can see the the nested dictionary is structured in the way that the heading styles define how many layers deep a branch is- heading3 is a sub branch of any preceding heading2 which is a sub-branch of any preceding heading1.

How can I go through the list and make another list of parent,children pairs so that I can make the tree from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it to work with the following

```
levels=[]
for i in range(0,len(header_styles)):
    header_styles[i][0]=int(header_styles[i][0].replace('Heading ',''))
    for j in texts:
        if header_styles[i][1]==j[0]:
            header_styles[i].append(j[1])
    levels.append(header_styles[i][0])

pairs=[]

def find_pairs(i_s,header_styles,levels):
    i_e=i_s
    while i_e > -1:
        level=1
        start,end = header_styles[i_s],header_styles[i_e]
        if end[0] < start[0]:
            print('match found')
            print(start,end)
            return (start[2],end[2],levels[i_s]+1,start[1])
            break
        level+=1
        i_e-=1


last = len(header_styles)-1
pairs=[]
for i in range(last,0,-1):
    print(i)
    pairs.append(find_pairs(i,header_styles,levels))

pairs=pairs[::-1]
pairs.insert(0,(0,'NA',1,'Essay'))
```

after making the parent-child list- I then make the nested dictionary:

```
queue_tuples=pairs
pGraph = {"_id":0,"name":queue_tuples[3],"children":[]}

for tuple in queue_tuples:
    level = tuple[2]
    g = pGraph["children"]
    for i in range(level-1):
        for e in g:
            if tuple[1]==e["_id"]:
                g = e["children"]
    flag = 0
    for e in g:
        if tuple[0]==e["_id"]:
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag==0:
        g.append({"_id":tuple[0],"name":tuple[3],"children":[]})


print(pGraph)
```